# pass query results to ajax callback

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a live search, where a user types something inside a text box and then via ajax results are fetched and added to a ul and in this specific case I am looking for usernames, so if a username is `johnny` and the user types in `jo` then `johnny` should come up and so on.

I have the ajax js code, a post method and a list model view of users, I am now trying to return the list but doesn't seem to be working.

my js:

```
$("input#searchtext").keyup(function (e) {

    var searchVal = $("input#searchtext").val();

    var url = "/profile/LiveSearch";

    $.post(url, { searchVal: searchVal }, function (data) {
console.log(data);
    });

});
```

LiveSearch view model

```
public class LiveSearchUserVM
    {
        public LiveSearchUserVM()
        {
        }

        public LiveSearchUserVM(UserDTO row)
        {
            FirstName = row.FirstName;
            LastName = row.LastName;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

the post method

```
[HttpPost]
        public List<string[]> LiveSearch(string searchVal)
        {
            // Init db
            Db db = new Db();

            List<LiveSearchUserVM> usernames = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Contains(searchVal)).Select(x => new LiveSearchUserVM(x)).ToList();

            return usernames;
        }
```

So basically I want to return a list (or something else) of columns that contain a specific string, and pass all the results to javascript thru ajax callback.

Comment: you can use success callback and result json result from controller

Comment: check my answer I hope it helps

Comment: Your action returns List <string[]> in signature but actually you are returning List <LiveSearchUserVM>. Does your code compiles successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the result as JSON alter your method to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LiveSearch(string searchVal)
{
    // Init db
    Db db = new Db();

    List<LiveSearchUserVM> usernames = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Contains(searchVal)).Select(x => new LiveSearchUserVM(x)).ToList();

    return Json(usernames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this   . The idea is to use success funtion

```
   $.ajax({
url : ""/profile/LiveSearch"",
type: "POST",
data : searchVal ,
success: function(data)
{
    //data - response from server
},
error: function ()
{

}
});
```

and return JsonResult from Post method

Comment: So I need to convert the list of view models into json first right? If so, how to do that first?

Comment: you can send complex object as well . For you case you have string so you can return JsonResult as well . But first try this to check that you got response from server the next step you can see how to send list/ complex object

Comment: I edited my q a bit, it had wrong code in the post method, I do not have a string but a list of view models as a result. I do get a successfull callback, the problem is how to read that list of objects as data callback parameter.

Comment: This should be done for you automatically when you return the generic list. .Net MVC is pretty good about converting complex objects to json for you.

Comment: it does not happen automatically and I had to convert it beforehand but didn't know how.